# How to make rebel-readline show more candiates

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

For example, when typing `d<TAB>` in the repl, it only shows 10 candidates.  I want it to show all candidates.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not supported as of version 0.1.4.

But you can clone the repository of [rebel-readline](https://github.com/bhauman/rebel-readline) to remove [this line](https://github.com/bhauman/rebel-readline/blob/6c314f8fe1cb44bde3a0511bf14d48157f89f6d7/rebel-readline/src/rebel_readline/clojure/line_reader.clj#L1017) in `line_reader.clj`:

```
(take 10)
```

To run it go in the `rebel-readline` sub-directory and type:

```
lein trampoline run -m rebel-readline.main
```

[Screenshot of rebel-readline without the (take 10) line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXvRm.png)